# MIPS Speedup Calculation

Tags: mips, cpu-speed

5 R-type instructions are to be executed on our original 5-stage (scalar) pipelined processor. There are no dependencies of any kind among the instructions.

If this same instruction sequence is executed instead on a degree-2 super-pipelined version of our processor, what speedup factor would be provided if no other changes are made?

I know that a degree-2 super-pipelined system splits each stage into two phases so that the time required for the two phases is the same as the original clock cycle time. I think the speedup would be 2, but that seems off.

Answer (score 0):

If the internal clock is multiplied by two, and assuming that there are no dependencies of any kind among the instructions, then you would see a speedup of factor 2 because the pipeline processes two instructions in every stage per outer clock cycle (the one not multiplied by factor 2)

The downside of this approach is that you have to provide an internal clock that is twice as fast, which makes the hardware design more complex.

Check [this chapter](http://es.scribd.com/doc/52812628/30/Superpipelined-Scalar-Processors#outer_page_71) for more details in the subject.